# grep the time duration from ping output

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ping

I wanted to write a bash code which just gives me the time of the pings.
I tried it with this:

```
ping -4 www.google.com | grep -oh "time=* ms"
```

But I know it wouldn't give me **just** the time but i thought it would reduce it to `time=30 ms`for example. It gives me no output though.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the PCRE mode on GNU `grep` by enabling the `-P` flag on, to extract the milli-seconds values alone

```
ping -4 www.google.com | grep -oP ".*time=\K\d+"
```

where the `\K` escape sequence stands for

> \K: [This sequence resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence.](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k)

Or you could do away with any GNU-ism tools needed and just use a POSIX `sed` to do

```
ping -4 www.google.com | sed -n 's/.*time=\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: Yes, thanks David for the feedback! using `()` was more of a habitual thing and sure its not needed

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you use is not the correct one.

Here is a [Perl regular expression](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expressions.htm) that does what you want. Note the use of single quotes which suppresses accidental expansion of any `*` that might be in the regular expression. `\d+` matches 1 or more decimals.

```
echo "time=12 ms" | grep -oh --perl-regex 'time=\d+ ms'
time=12 ms
```

The `-h` can be left out in this case, too.

Personally, I'm always using Perl regex once it gets anywhere near a little complex. The default for `grep` is ["basic regular expression"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#bre). You can also have ["extended regular expressions"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere) using `--extended-regexp` option. See also [POSIX basic and extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) at Wikipedia.